# How to calculate the Vout/Vin in this circuit? And how to write this circuit in a simulator like PSPICE? (buffer)

Tags: signal, simulation, impedance, design, buffer

This question is about this circuit, a signal conditioning circuit.

[image: An image of a eletrical circuit]

I am trying to the discover the Vout/Vin, I think it is one but I can't demonstrate it. I can't figure out why these resistors and capacitor are needed, why the current would go through Vout if has a path to the ground in the middle. I tried to  design in pspice to study it more but I never used a simulator and I am confused with what to do with the loose ends like Vin, 5V and Vout, especially the Vout end.

[image: The circuit in pspice]

I tried to simulate the circuit like this but the voltage over the resistor im testing is 0.  If someone could please explain how this circuit is working and help me with these doubts I would be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: From your writing, I don't think you are ready to understand a simple answer. There is too much missing from your conceptual "library." And it would take a lot of time to build it out so that a reasonable answer here could then apply. And looking at your newly added schematic at the bottom, I can see that you also lack an understanding about opamps, useful frequencies, input voltages, and output loading. You've got a long ways to go. Perhaps you can pick a small part of the above?

Comment: Yeah I am very new to this and some concepts I studied a while ago, if could give me a simple answer I won't understand it fully but it would do understand what a I need to study, it is my first time in many thing of this area. If you could explain to me the small part that you thkin would help me more to begin understading I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The op-amp is connected as a "voltage follower" - its output voltage will be a copy of the voltage on its "+" input.

The two 10 Meg resistors bias the op-amp's positive input to half the supply voltage, so an AC input signal won't drive the op-amp output to supply or Ground.

The 9K and 1K resistors are a voltage divider.

Comment: Thank you, this already helped a lot. If it not much to ask do you have any quick tip on what to change on the schematic to make it it right?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it right"?  To ensure that the signal is not clipped (distorted), the input signal must be less than 5V peak-to-peak or 1.78V RMS.

Comment: My output signal in red is stucked in 0V, and I think i have done something wrong. But it is okay this helped a lot I could oper another question for the simulator and design.

Comment: Your output is at the top of R6 - the "V-" probe.  The "V+" probe is Ground, so must be 0 V.